# Swing: table with header row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table showing a list of objects; let's call them `Employee` for clarity's sake.

The table shows `Employee` objects that are child objects of a given parent object which is also an `Employee`. What I would like to do is show a special header row with the parent object, either above (if possible) or below the normal column heading, but in a different color. I want the columns of the parent object row to be resized in sync with the rest of the table, and I don't want the parent object to be selectible.

(Basically I want to show a self-contained table of child objects, along with a separate parent "context" which has the same fields.)

Is there a good way to do this? (one table with a special row? two tables, where the one for the parent context object is only 1 row vertical, and horizonally resizes to match the other?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should make the special row always be rendered at row 0 in the table, using whatever renderer you need to change the color etc.  That way you get the resizing for free.

In order to make this row unselectable, I think you'll need to override the [createDefautSelectionModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#createDefaultSelectionModel%28%29) method to your own implementation of [ListSelectionModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html).  You can probably override the [DefaultListSelectionModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.html) to ignore a value of 0 (first row) in the [setAnchorSelectionIndex](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.html#setAnchorSelectionIndex%28int%29) method and [setLeadSelectionIndex](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.html#setAnchorSelectionIndex%28int%29) methods.

Should work, but haven't tested.

Comment: thanks, I bailed on the non-selectable, but otherwise it works. (I've been using GlazedLists and finally figured out that CompositeList allows you to merge two lists in sequence, so I made a CompositeList with the first list including my "special" row.

Comment: I've seen a lot of good things about GlazedLists - I'll have to check it out.  Glad you have everything working